# Unable deploy mule application in mule stand alone server

Tags: mule-studio, mule-esb

During development of mule application in any point studio 6 and run time environment is 3.9 project running fine. But while deployment on  mule stand alone server getting following error:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft .
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems in your dwl file, would you please take a look of dwl once, and if possible share the same dwl and payload before the transformer component.